# Android app is not building after change the android studio version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I created an Android app using the android studio (2016) with the following parameters

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.stl.sciocardio.app.androidapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Also, I use third party projects inside the project as well. When I change the Android studio 2020 the app is not built or even not detected as an android project. It gives me the following error once I try to rebuild it

```
Unable to find Gradle tasks to build: [:app, :, :GraphView-master]. 
            Build mode: REBUILD. 
            Tests: None.
```

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Delete folders [build, .idea, .gradle]
2. Invalidate Caches / Restart

If it does not get resolved, then repeat the above step by removing
`include ':app'`  from `settings.gradle`